# Getting users groups when getting a user

Tags: azure-active-directory

I'm trying to get a website up and running where the user has to log in using an Azure AD account. The user themselves are usually either a member of one of two groups. Is there any way within Azure AD of getting that group ID and/or name returned as a claim on the identity token?

Comment: The article below explains group claim in more details. You may refer to that. http://www.dushyantgill.com/blog/2014/12/10/authorization-cloud-applications-using-ad-groups/

Answer (score 2):

You can edit the manifest of the app.

You can find it in the new portal via Azure Active Directory -> App Registrations -> Your app -> Manifest.

Then you need to set the `groupMembershipClaims` property to either `"SecurityGroup"` or `"All"`.

```
"groupMembershipClaims": "SecurityGroup"
```

The ids will then be returned in id tokens for your app. SecurityGroup only includes AAD security groups, All also includes Office 365 groups.